# Zend Layout for specific Actions

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, view-helpers, zend-controller, zend-layout

Is there a simple way of just enable a layout for the actions of a controller, instead of disabling it in all other actions of other controllers in Zend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        // For all actions
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
    }

    public function myAction()
    {
        // For specific action
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('my');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And the actions that don't use the layout, need some code too?

Comment: So I need to disable the layout in all other actions? Is this better then making a default empty layout to be used on all other actions?

Comment: I don't know about your application. What is better you should know better than me.

Comment: Ok, in my case, I prefer to make a layout that just have "<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>" for all actions an then specify the other layout manually on the other actions. Thanks for the help ;)